# How can I view news by date Today or Yesterday, or a specific date?

Tags: php, sql

I have table in a sql db

```
CREATE TABLE `News` (
`Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Title` varchar(100),
`Time` int(100)
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and I have a page View.php

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_config, $config);
$query_m_list = "SELECT * FROM News Where Time='today' ORDER BY Id Asc";
$m_list= mysql_query($query_m_list, $config) or die(mysql_error());
$row_m_list= mysql_fetch_assoc($m_list);
$totalRows_m_list = mysql_num_rows($m_list);
?>
```

How can I view news by date Today or yesterday, or a specific date from the table?

Comment: (`INT(100)` is useless, because an `INT` is always the same size: 4 bytes. The number only affects `ZEROFILL` results.)

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You should use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.summary.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Time columns type to `datetime` and then use the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM M_News Where date(`Time`)<=CURRENT_DATE() 
AND date(`Time`)>=DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY Id Asc
```

Above query will give you the news of the today and yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

since you store time as (int) data type you need to use time_ago function to calculate seconds,hours,days,weeks, month and year. you can download jquery timeago here [TimeAgo](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

Once the timeago functions returns a specific value you can then ponder about fetching correct data you want.